# What tools can recover or do forensic analysis on deleted registry entry?

Tags: windows, forensics, registry

I'm reading [this article](https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2019/01/digging-up-the-past-windows-registry-forensics-revisited.html), in the `Deleted Recovery Example` it has the following picture, `Figure 8 shows an example of a data recovery error by a popular registry forensics tool`

[image]

I have two questions

1. Does anyone know what software this is?
2. I've tried to create a scheduled task and deleted it, but there's no *.regtrans-ms files in c:\windows\system32\config\txr:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Registry Explorer/RECmd from -- https://ericzimmerman.github.io/#!index.md